# I get the error C2440 but i don't know how to fix it, please can someone help me?

Tags: c++

I keep getting the error C2440!

It says 'return:' cannot convert from 'bool' to 'HCURSOR'.

```
    if (!addrSetCursor)
    return false;
```

Thats where I get the error from and I think its giving me the error because of the code

```
    HCURSOR Discord::SetCursor(HCURSOR hCursor)
{
    static uintptr_t addrSetCursor = NULL;

    if (!addrSetCursor)
    {
        addrSetCursor = Helper::PatternScan(GetDiscordModuleBase(),
                                            "40 53 48 83 EC 20 0F B6 05 ? ? ? ? 48 8B D9 84 C0 74 4F");

        #ifdef DEVELOPER
        printf("SetCursor: 0x%p\n", addrSetCursor);
        #endif
    }
```

This isnt my code its from a github. Please help :(

Comment: Change what to return to proper thing (maybe `nullptr`) instead of `false`.

Comment: Show the full code needed to understand the question, not disjointed excerpts of it. We don't know where that `return` is and hence whether it's returning the right type of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is expected to return `HCURSOR`, and `false` can't be converted to `HCURSOR`.

Try `return NULL` instead of `return false` (assuming the caller of `Discord::SetCursor` can handle a `NULL` result).

BTW [the code on "GitHub"](https://nigga.ltd/suckmydick/covid69-crack/blob/master/Cheeto/DiscordHook/Discord.cpp#L183) has `return 0` at that location, so maybe you have an old version.

Comment: Your BTW - interesting.

Comment: Thank you that worked, it loads fully now and im not getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean `false` in C++ is not considered by the compiler to be equivalent to integer constant `0`, so cannot be assigned to a pointer variable (if you look at the declaration of `HCURSOR` you will see that it is a pointer to a `struct`).  To be fair to the author of the code, this was probably not the case when he wrote it.

Anyway, the fix is easy: just return `nullptr`, or if you can't do that for some reason, return `0`.